# How to make a Wrapper or Layout to avoid repetition on several NextJS pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, wrapper

I've been working with Nextjs for a while and I'm trying to avoid repetitive tasks. For a dynamic site, the menu and footer which are repeated on the whole page cause me a serious problem. To avoid this, I thought of making a Wrapper that I repeat on all the pages and pass the data in props.

But what I'm doing is making a wrapper that loads the data and won't be repeated on all the pages.

Look at the picture to get an idea of what I say

https://www.figma.com/file/u4okWHg3CpbgLPpZEiYJxI/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. Making a wrapper (or `<Layout>`) is a standard practice for avoiding repeating page layout code. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. My way of making a wrapper does not allow me to avoid all repetition with Nextjs. That's why I'm here. Click the link to view https://www.figma.com/file/u4okWHg3CpbgLPpZEiYJxI/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1

Comment: Please see [ask]. We don't work with images of code here.

Comment: Could middleware be used here?

Comment: To retrieve the shared data for the layout you can either to fetch it server-side at the page/`_app` level and pass it down to the layout, or fetch it client-side on the the layout component directly.

Answer (score 0):

Layout and wrapper are two different things.

- BaseLayout used to share a common section across multiple pages.

  ```
  const BaseLayout= (props) => {
    const {
      className,user,navClass,loading,children,noSideBar,} = props;
    // Define renderer to render the view
    const renderer = () => (
      <div className={`baselayout ${className}`}>
        {noSideBar ? "" : <SideBar />}
        <main>
          {/*    Prop drilling here */}
          <Header className={navClass} user={user} loading={loading} />
          {children}
          <Footer />
        </main>
      </div>
    );
    return <> {renderer()} </>;
  };

  export default BaseLayout;
  ```

Then you use it inside a page

```
const AboutMe = () => {

  return (
    <BaseLayout user={data} loading={loading}>
      {/* YOUR PAGE COMPONENT HERRE */}
    </BaseLayout>
  );
};
```

- Wrappers are used to create and support basic UI elements based on the data or prop values. These wrapper contain an instance of another class or component and provide a new way to use an object. For example provide pages to an admin

  ```
  function withAuth(Component) {
    return (role) => {
      return (props) => {
        // an hook to get the props. based on this we decide what to render
        const { data, loading } = useGetUser();
        if (loading) {
          return <p>Loading...</p>;
        }
        if (!data) {
          return <Redirect to="/api/v1/login" />;
        } else {
          // if not authorized redirect to login
          if (role && !isAuthorized(data, role)) {
            return <Redirect to="/api/v1/login" />;
          }
          // if it is authorized return compoentn
          return <Component user={data} loading={loading} {...props} />;
        }
      };
    };
  }
  export default withAuth;
  ```

Then maybe we have a page for only admin

```
const OnlyAdmin = ({ user, loading }: { user: IUser; loading: true }) => {
  return (
    <BaseLayout user={user} loading={loading}>
        <h1>I am Admin Page - Hello {user.name}</h1>
    </BaseLayout>
  );
};
// we are wrapping the component to pass a new property
export default withAuth(OnlyAdmin)("admin");
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've done for that situation is have a context that gets the header and footer data client side and store it as JSON in window.sessionStorage. Then your header and footer are only loaded when blank or when invalidated by 'something' e.g certain routes or user login status changes.

Keeps things very fast and avoids needless delays. If you are going for full SSR you could do the same thing with server side sessions.

Comment: This solution seems more concrete to me. But I will know if it will not cause an SEO problem since the data comes with CSG. This is why I am looking for a solution that can allow me to recover the data with Static Generation (with a getStaticProps)

Comment: Google, at least, discounts your boilerplate. Also they claim to now index dynamic sites.